# Count of unique values that occur more than 100 in a data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, count, unique

I have a dataframe which has a column name called "drug_name" and I would like to get a list of all the unique values in the column and the number of time it has occured.
For this reason , I use

```
print(df['drug_name'].value_counts())
```

and

> pd.value_counts(df.drug_name)
>
> Both of these work fine but the length is very long since there is many variables that occur once. So I would like to know if there is a parameter that allows me to set the number of occurences to more than 100 to reduce the length and see only the relevant variables.

Comment: unique_names =   `df['drug_name'].unique()`

Comment: So should I write , df['drug_name'].unique(100) to get the list of variables that has a count of atleast 100 ?

Comment: no, but a filter would work....  if you have a sample dataframe that you would like to share, then i can show you how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would solve the problem.

```py
import pandas as pd

# sample dict with repeated items
d = {'drug_name':['hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'bye', 'bye']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
print()

# this gets the unique values with their respective frequency
df_counted = df['drug_name'].value_counts()
print(df_counted)
print()


# filter to values > 3
df_filtered = df_counted[df_counted>2]
print(df_filtered)
```

this is the sample dataframe:

```
  drug_name
0     hello
1     hello
2     hello
3       bye
4       bye
```

These are the unique values counted:

```
hello    4
bye      2
```

These are the unique values > n:

```
hello    4
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. But would you know how to save this as a file?

Comment: Your are welcome.   If the problem is solved, please mark the question as solved and upvote as this helps other users.    What would you like to save the final Dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the values afterwards:

```
s = df['drug_name'].value_counts()
s[s.ge(100)]
```

Alternative, as `value_counts` is sorted by decreasing count, you can only look at the top ones:

```
df['drug_name'].value_counts().head(20) # 20 top items
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. But would you know how to save this output as a file?

Comment: @Jan `s[s.ge(100)].to_csv('filename.csv') `